# Click Once Deployment Over Internet - The webpage cannot be displayed

Tags: clickonce

I published a WPF application on my IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008) and over my network using Click-Once. I could open the webpage (with the proper www.webpage.com:8082 address, not using localhost or computer name as URL). 
When doing it over the network, I get the nice webpage with the "Install" button and so on that I am used to with Click-Once.

Now I tried to install the application from outside my network. It seems that I can connect to the webpage, but I am getting a "The webpage cannot be displayed". Under "likely clause" it says:
"Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed".

I used IE9 at home on my network, while when I connect from the internet I use IE8.

Of course I tried to google it, but with little success.....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to configure NAT on your firewall, so request to port 8082 are redirected to the machine hosting the app. Also note that if you have multiple websites on port 8082, that host headers must be used (not likely though).

Also note that the update url in the clickonce manifest must corresponds exactly to where the files can be located - e.g. http://www.pageweb.com/8082/clickonceAppBinariesFolder